# Metric of $SO(3)$ : Why is there $\frac{1}{8}$ in front of this scalar product?

Tags: metric-spaces, lie-groups, inner-products, matrix-calculus, rotations

I'm considering the rotation group, as described by $SO(3)$ (i.e the set of $3 \times 3$ orthogonal matrices $R$ of determinant 1, with real components) and $SU(2)$ (the set of $2 \times 2$ complex matrices $U$ of determinant 1).  The elements of these two groups could be represented like this (the unit matrix is implied implicitely):
\begin{align}
R(\alpha, n_k) &= 1 \cos \alpha + \sum_{k = 1}^3 \lambda_k \, n_k \sin \alpha + n \, n^{\top} (1 - \cos \alpha) \quad \in SO(3), \tag{1} \\
U(\alpha, n_k) &= e^{i \vec{\sigma} \, \cdot \, \vec{n} \, \alpha / 2} = 1 \cos (\alpha/2) + i \sum_{k = 1}^3 \sigma_k \, n_k \sin (\alpha/2) \quad \in SU(2), \tag{2}
\end{align}
where $\lambda_k$ ($k = 1, 2, 3$) are three $3 \times 3$ skew-symetrical matrices that generate the rotations, and $\sigma_k$ are the three $2 \times 2$ Pauli matrices.  The components $n_k$ are three real numbers defining the rotation axis.  We could write these components as this:
$$n_k = \{ \sin\vartheta \cos \varphi, \: \sin \vartheta \sin \varphi, \: \cos \vartheta \}. \tag{3}$$
Of course, $\alpha$ is the rotation angle.

Now, I define a scalar product in $SU(2)$ as a trace:
$$\langle \, U_1, \, U_2 \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \, \mathrm{Tr}(U_1^{\dagger} \, U_2), \qquad U_1, \, U_2 \, \in \, SU(2).\tag{4}$$
Calculating the differential $dU$ gives us a metric on $SU(2)$ (I set $\chi \equiv \alpha / 2$ to simplify things):
$$ds^2 = \frac{1}{2} \, \mathrm{Tr}(dU^{\dagger} \, dU) = d\chi^2 + \sin^2 \chi \, (d\vartheta^2 + \sin^2 \vartheta \, d\varphi^2).\tag{5}$$
This is a well known metric on $\mathcal{S}_3$, the 3-sphere.  This is fine, since $SU(2)$ is a compact Lie group, which have the topology of that sphere.

But then I tried to do the same with $SO(3)$ (the calculations are very messy in this case).  I got this:
$$\frac{1}{8} \, \mathrm{Tr}(dR^{\top} \, dR) = d\chi^2 + \sin^2 \chi \, (d\vartheta^2 + \sin^2 \vartheta \, d\varphi^2).\tag{6}$$
The fraction $\frac{1}{8}$ on the left part puzzles me.  Why this factor, instead of $\frac{1}{3}$?  This trace of $3 \times 3$ matrices doesn't look like a scalar product.  My interpretation of (6) is lacking.  How can we define a proper scalar product and Riemanian metric on $SO(3)$ that would show the 3-sphere hidden in it?

Comment: If you multiply a scalar product by a (positive) constant, it is still a scalar product inducing exactly the same topology. So you can use any prefactor that is convenient to you. So how did you come up with the $1/2$ in (4) ? and why is the $1/8$ in (6) more confusing? If you are looking for a canonical choice of scalar product on a Lie algebra, you should look at its "Killing form"

Comment: @Simon, well, I'm not sure what to think about the numbers in front of the trace (or in any inner product, actually).  In (4), the fraction is "natural" since it keeps the normalisation of all the "unit" $2 \times 2$ matrices (unit and Pauli matrices).  In (6), I would have expected $\frac{1}{3}$ or $\frac{1}{2}$ (instead of $\frac{1}{8}$ !) for the same reason.

Comment: Maybe (6) doesn't have a "nice and natural looking" fraction to normalise all $3 \times 3$ "unit matrices", because the usual orthogonal matrices (the unit, the three skew-symmetrical $\lambda_k$ and the Gell-Mann matrices) aren't normalized? We have $\mathrm{Tr}\, \mathbb{I} = 3$, $\mathrm{Tr} (\lambda_k \lambda_k) = 2$, and so on.